# How to add a class remove a class on reaching a specific div (overflow hidden)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I am developing a full page website using fullpage.js. I have a fixed nav bar on it. I want to change the logo on navbar by adding and removing a css class. I have tried this code :

```
function sticky_relocate() {
  var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
  var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
  if (window_top > div_top)
    $('#sticky').addClass('stick')
  else
    $('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
}

$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
  sticky_relocate();
});
```

but it is not working may be because of overflow:hidden used in fullpage.js and $(window).scrollTop() gives 0 value all time.

Anybody has any solution(I am new to jquery)?

**Edit:** Code is working fine if I don't use fullpage.js plugin. fullpage.js uses overflow:hidden and position:relative in body tag to hide scrollbar. example website http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

Comment: http://www.cssnewbie.com/simple-jquery-stylesheet-switcher/#.UprppcRDtih

Comment: You should use the callbacks `afterLoad` or `onLeave` for those purposes. Take a look at this example in which the menu is fade out or in depending on the slides: http://jsfiddle.net/J8hqM/8/

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the scrollbar is not on the body but on another element, if this is the case then:

Find out which element has the scrollbar by using inspect element directly on the scrollbar.

Then get (element with scrollbar).scrollTop() instead of window.scrollTop()

Replace

```
var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
```

with

```
var withScrollbar = $('#elementWithScrollbar');
var window_top = $(withScrollbar).scrollTop();
```

Comment: I have edited my post for more clarification. Please have a look.